# Firebase returning a null dataSnapshot when loading into nested objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to load an object from my database but the dataSnapshot is not returning anything. I have a structure like this:

[image: ""]

This is my `Event` object:

```
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private String eventName, eventDescription;
    private Author author;
    private Venue venue;
    private ArrayList<Comment> comments;
    private ArrayList<Like> likes;

    public Event() {
    }

    public Event(@NonNull String eventName, String eventDescription, Author author, Venue venue) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
        this.author = author;
        this.venue = venue;

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Venue getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(Venue venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    public String getEventDescription() {
        return eventDescription;
    }

    public void setEventDescription(String eventDescription) {
        this.eventDescription = eventDescription;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(ArrayList<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public List<Like> getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(ArrayList<Like> likes) {
        this.likes = likes;

    }
}
```

And this is my code:

```
        Event event;
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        databaseReference.child("Event").child("0").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);


            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

The event object comes back as null even though I'm pretty sure the path is correct

Comment: At first glance the JSON and Java code seem to match up. If you print `event` right after reading it, is it actually `null`? Or are you using it elsewhere? If so, can you edit the last code fragment to show what's actually going wrong?

Comment: Upon debugging, I notice that the Event object is null

Comment: That's not good enough. Where do you notice that? Is there some way that you can modify the code to show that? Please study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it's by far best if you put all details in the code. For example, can you `System.out.println(event)` right after reading it and then show us the updated code and the output you get in your question?